# How do you find out if a polar curve retraces itself?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I was solving a question where you were supposed to find the area of petal formed by a polar curve. But the answer I got was greater than the actual answer by a factor of 2. Apparenty few polar curves retrace themselves, how do you find out wherther a polar curve retraces itself?

Answer (score 1):

If your function is $r(\theta)$, with the polar radius expressed as a function of the polar angle, then it retraces itself if $r(\theta) = r(\theta + 2\pi)$ (or possibly if $r(\theta) = -r(\theta + \pi)$).

Comment: The question I did satisfies the first condition you mentioned, but can you explain the reason?

Comment: @NikhilKrishna Because an angle of $\theta$ and an angle of $\theta + 2\pi$ gives the same ray out from the origin. So if the value of $r$ is the same, then that means that the graph from the two (technically different) angles will overlap exactly. The second condition is basically the same thing, except an angle of $\theta$ is exactly in the opposite direction of an angle of $\theta + \pi$, so if the value of $r$ is completely opposite as well, that means the graph once again overlaps.